# Demarcating iOS API Availability

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

When working with Mac Catalyst, it's standard to use the following conditional syntax to mark availability for entire methods ->

```
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
- (void)customMethodOnlyForCatalyst {

}
#endif
```

Is there an equivalent conditional for API availability? ie, something akin to the following...

```
#if @available(iOS 13.0, *)
- (void)customMethodOnlyForiOS13AndAbove {

}
#endif
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `API_AVAILABLE` macro.

The documentation is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/marking_api_availability_in_objective-c).

For example:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
- (void) newMethod API_AVAILABLE(ios(11), macosx(10.13));
@end
```

`newMethod` will only be available on iOS 11 and macOS 10.13.

To use your example:

```
- (void)customMethodOnlyForiOS13AndAbove API_AVAILABLE(ios(13)) { }
```